# Python create exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

i write a program that detected and recognition visitors with face_recognition . i try to make exe file with pyinstaller .it's make .exe file but when i run the .exe it has an error.

```
E:\python source\python examples\Visitors\dist>main_window.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_window.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "e:\python source\python-3.9.1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path=None, target=None):
  File "face_recognition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "e:\python source\python-3.9.1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path=None, target=None):
  File "face_recognition\api.py", line 20, in <module>
RuntimeError: Unable to open C:\Users\SHAHRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI144802\face_recognition_models\models\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
[13080] Failed to execute script main_window
```

my source code on github :
"** https://github.com/shahram-arefhakimi/Visitors_with_PySide2 **"

Comment: The error says it cannot find `C:\Users\SHAHRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI144802\face_recognition_models\models\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`. Is there something there?

Comment: hi , Unfortunately not. This directory seems to be created when the exe file is created. i Don't have this path

Comment: i added my source  code on github .

Answer (score 0):

I have come through this issue previously and there is a solution to it. When you type this in the terminal (cmd or PowerShell):

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w filename.py
```

if you remove the

```
-w
```

so it is just

```
pyinstaller --onefile filename.py
```

then you will be able to run the exe fine

This will work 99% but if not, then there is a possibility that you have an error in your code

Comment: i use the code ,but its not work . my source code is on github please check it ...  thank you.